# CSS import not working in .storybook/preview.js after adding 'storybook-addon-next',

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, next.js

Hi I am using Storybook 6.4.22 with Next 12.1.5 and Typescript 4.4.2(Node 16). I have to add global fonts for our stories. I tried adding that in preview.js and it worked fine initially. I had to use 'storybook-addon-next' because some of our components are pulling info out of configs(getConfig()?.serverRuntimeConfig?.config). After adding the addon my global import of fonts has stopped working.
Thanks in advance for your help.

### storybook/Main.js

```
module.exports = {
stories: ['../src//*.stories.mdx', '../src//*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
addons: [
'@storybook/addon-links',
'@storybook/addon-essentials',
'@storybook/addon-interactions',
'storybook-addon-tags',
'storybook-addon-next',
],
framework: '@storybook/react',
core: {
builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5',
},
}
```

### storybook/preview.js

```
import '@UI/palette/build/web/fonts/fonts-cdn.css' //css import

export const parameters = {
actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
controls: {
matchers: {
color: /(background|color)$/i,
date: /Date$/,
},
},
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you made sure to install the `storybook-addon-next` package?

Comment: Hey @abney317, yes i have the storybook-addon-next package installed
    "storybook-addon-next": "^1.6.2",

I didn't get any errors